# Inputpicker dispose filter after setting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, dropdown

I am using "[Jquery inputpicker plugin](https://www.inputpicker.com/)" which its references can be find [here](https://github.com/ukalpa/inputpicker).
I use this plugin for dropdown menus. I initiate my drop down using below code:

```
$('#test').inputpicker({
    data:[
        {value:"1",text:"USD"},
        {value:"2",text:"EUR"},
        {value:"3",text:"CNY"}
    ],
    fields:[
        {name:'value',text:'Id'},
        {name:'text',text:'Title'}
    ],
    autoOpen: true,
    headShow: false,
    filterOpen: true,
    fieldText : 'text',
    fieldValue: 'value'
    });
```

I can set selected item of my list by code:

```
$('#test').inputpicker('val', 1); // selecting "USD"
```

after setting the value of my field , when users try to open the drop down and look for another item, there is no item visible but "USD". For selecting another item, user should erase all characters manually, then other items will be displayed.

I am looking for a way to show all items after setting selected item.

I have created a sample of my code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/6eL9pfdw/

Comment: Are you sure you are "selecting" an item and not setting what the dropdown data is?

Comment: Yes, after clearing my input other items will be appeared.

Comment: can you make your code runnable?

Comment: check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/6eL9pfdw/

Comment: I checked your code that was giving this behavior because you have set `filterOpen: true` . I removed that and it was working fine check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zxp178uw/)

Comment: @swati  If I set filterOpen to false,  I can't filter my items anymore.

Comment: If i type any value its working fine in above `fiddle` i.e : its highlight rows when match .

Comment: remove "filterOpen: true" , then type "U" in text box. you can still see "CNY" wich  is not match whith my filter "U".

Answer (score 0):

Hacky but it works:

Set the `filterOpen: false`, this will prevent filtering the data on the first open.

Bind to `focus` event and set the `filterOpen = true`. This will re-enable the filtering.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').inputpicker("val" , "1");
});

$('#test').inputpicker({
    data:[
        {value:"1",text:"USD"},
        {value:"2",text:"EUR"},
        {value:"3",text:"CNY"}
    ],
    fields:[
        {name:'value',text:'Id'},
        {name:'text',text:'Title'}
    ],
    autoOpen: true,
    headShow: false,
    filterOpen: false,
    fieldText : 'text',
    fieldValue: 'value'
});

$('#inputpicker-1').on("focus", function() {
    $('#test').inputpicker("set" , "filterOpen", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should deactivate the filter at the start of the code otherwise, it will display only what is provided according to the content of the textbox.

According to the document of `InputPicker`, setting `filterOpen` to `false` deactivates filter and all your data will be displayed.

[image]

More precisely, you only have to set it to false in your initial code

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').inputpicker("val" , "1");
});

$('#test').inputpicker({
    data:[
        {value:"1",text:"USD"},
        {value:"2",text:"EUR"},
        {value:"3",text:"CNY"}
    ],
    fields:[
        {name:'value',text:'Id'},
        {name:'text',text:'Title'}
    ],
    autoOpen: true,
    headShow: false,
    filterOpen: false,
    fieldText : 'text',
    fieldValue: 'value'
});
```